# java regex match after certain phrase

Tags: java

I'm new to using Regex, I've been going through a rake of tutorials but I haven't found one that applies to what I want to do,

I want to search for something, but return everything following it but not the search string itself

e.g. "/Sites/sample1103/documentLibrary/"

search after "/Sites/" and before documentLibrary

return "sample1103"

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you please post what you have tried? What has worked and not worked? StackOverflow tends to frown upon posts asking people to do all of the work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\/Sites\/([\w]+)
```

First it matches your search term. The round braces mean you define a group. The group captures the following string. All you need to do is return group 1 of the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\/Sites\/(.*)\/documentLibrary` as regex and group(1) would return you sample1103. Also if you want to be more specific and have to capture just one value between the forward slashes use `\/Sites\/([^\/]+)\/documentLibrary`